# CakePHP 3 shell script increase execution timeout limit

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, php-7.0

I'm new at **cakephp 3** and I'm developing an app using it and php 7.0.

I have a shell script at **/app/src/Shell**, that connects to a webservice and consumes JSON data.

The problem is, it's taking more than 30 secs to retrieve the data.

I already tried to change the `max_execution_time` at **/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini** and **/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini**, but no success.

Am I missing something?
Is there a config in cakephp that needs to be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing PHP timeout with object and webservice timeout. PHP timeout is 0 by default in CLI. The problem is the timeout of the webservice and the connection to this one (Client object etc). Those timeouts are hard to change (can be raised a bit but will result in flaky behavior). You should make sure you never do requests to webservices beyond a few seconds!

Comment: Thanks @mark for the clarification. I'm in touch with the webservice developer to improve API performance. Using Postman for testing, the response takes an average of 46 to 50 seconds to retrieve the data.

Comment: How exactly do you make call to webservice? please, provide more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
After what @mark said in his comment, I did some research and found out the solution. The thing is, I'm using the Http Client Class of cakephp 3. Reading the docs, I realized that you can pass the 'timeout' parameter at the moment that the object is been created.

But, also following the @mark's comment, change the timeout value, is not a good practice.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: cakephp now composer based. not sure about Http Client Class, but in several another http client libraries changing of timeout is normal and not lead to any issues. For example you can use http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation 

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=timeout#timeout

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are looking to the good configuration file, of the PHP your are using, thanks to this command:

```
php -ini |grep "php.ini"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bsquare. My localhost is using /cli php.ini. But I already tried to change the 'max_execution_time' in /cli/php.ini, restarted the service, but no success.

Comment: It is strange, Try putting [this instruction](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) at beginning of your script to be 100% sure your configuration is well taken care.

Comment: Not a valid answer, see my comment.